# What's going on with the not awarded bounty points?

Tags: discussion, bounty

What's going on with the not awarded bounty points? Are they lost for good?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From the help page](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) (relevant excerpts):

> - All bounties are paid for up front and non-refundable under any circumstances
>
> reputation refunds are not available if no answers are received as a result of the bounty
>
> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days [...]. **If there's no answer meeting those criteria, the bounty is not awarded to anyone.**

The points are simply lost.